# Using requirejs with retinajs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am using [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org) and am calling in [retinajs](http://retinajs.com/) as a plugin. I am using the shim along with a jQuery dependancy:

```
....
'plugins/retina.min': {
        'deps': ['jquery']
    }
....
```

I then init my application:

```
requirejs(['./main'], function(App) {
    App.init();
});
```

"main.js":

```
define(['jquery', 'foo', 'bar', 'plugins/domReady!', 'plugins/retina.min'], function($, foo, bar, retina) {....});
```

My logo on my page is getting updated correctly, however it seems I am running into a timing issue. Further down the page (or even subsequent page views) the script is getting executed before the page is ready.

Retina.js auto-exectues so there isn't a method to initialize per say. Is there a way to "call" a jquery plugin that auto-executes with require js?

This is wrong, but I think this is something along the lines of what I need:

```
define(['jquery', 'foo', 'bar', 'plugins/domReady!', 'plugins/retina.min'], function($, foo, bar, retina) {
    var App = {
        init: function() {

           retina.init(); // This doesn't exist
           <script src="/plugins/retina.js"></script> // Not even close to valid, but this is what I need.
         }

     };
    return App;
});
```

Thank you for your time and suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure you're linking to the right "Retina" project? If I go there and look at the source, I do not see anything related to jQuery. This [project](https://github.com/tylercraft/jQuery-Retina), however, *is* a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Yeah [this](http://retinajs.com/) is the plugin I was/am using. I'm open to anything else though. I will check this one out. Perhaps it will fit my needs better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
define(['jquery', 'foo', 'bar', 'plugins/domReady!'], function($, foo, bar) {
    var App = {
        init: function() {
            require(['plugins/retina.min'], function(){
                // This is straight from retina.js's source: https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/blob/master/src/retina.js#L142
                if (Retina.isRetina()) {
                    Retina.init(window);
                }
            });
         }
     };
    return App;
});
```

Comment: I'm just stepping into the require scene - This looks like the path I'm trying to go down. Thank you!